# Convert C# HashSet to F# Set

Tags: c#, .net, f#

I have code that is shared between F# and C# and I need to convert between the C# HashSet and the F# Set.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there are additional constraints on the types used for a [F#-Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353619.aspx) - if you can support them you can just use [Set.ofSeq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340225.aspx) to convert it from your HashSet - but I would just use the original HashSet (maybe encapsulated) - no need for the additional work.

Comment: The original HashSet doesn't work well when using recursion to add elements nor using pattern matching with Set.empty

Comment: Or, even shorter, use the [`set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353747.aspx) function.